# Internal Field associated with electronic polarization of neutral atom due external field

Tags: electric-fields, polarization

A neutral atom (say hydrogen) placed in an external electric field will undergo electronic polarization. So we have a separation in +ve and -ve charge centers (that actually creates a dipole out of a neutral situation). The force required to pull the charge centers and create this dipole is provided by the external field. The dipole (once created) will have an internal field associated with it. In order to prevent ionization, the field has to be same in magnitude and opposite in direction compared to the external field. Am I correct in this explanation ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say it is 'to prevent ionization' - the net charges distributions shift under the influence of the external field until their separation cancels out that field internally, providing an equal-and-opposite force. (Note that you can ionize atoms/molecules in a strong enough field.)

Comment: Maybe I didn't put it in correct words. I meant, if it reaches equilibrium and undergoes electronic polarization, the "internal field has to be same in magnitude and opposite in direction compared to external field strength" - this would be the correct explanation right ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise there would still be a net force on the charge distribution that it would respond to.

Comment: One last quick question here: If I shift from a neutral Hydrogen atom to a dielectric medium (sperical), does the argument of opposite and equal internal field still work ? [I asked this because of this: http://matthieu.lagouge.free.fr/elecstq/sphere.xhtml]